# Why doesn't C++ require a "new" statement to initialize std::vector?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

Consider:

```
/* bar.h */
class bar{
    /* Standard stuff omitted */
    std::vector<my_obj*> foo;
};

/* bar.cpp */
bar::bar(){
    // foo = new std::vector<my_obj*>(); <-- Why don't I need this line??
    foo.push_back(new my_obj());
}
```

Why does this code work even though we didn't assign *foo* a new instance of *std::vector*?

Comment: What they said. Also, I can't recommend `foo.push_back(new my_obj());` because where are you going to free the memory there?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Because C++ is not C#/Java.

```
std::vector<my_obj*> foo;
```

This is a definition of an *object*, not a reference as in C#/Java. An object is a living instance of a type.

```
new std::vector<my_obj*>()
```

This expression returns a *pointer*. It returns a `std::vector<my_obj*>*`, which is *not* the same type as `foo` (the `*` at the end is what makes them different). `foo` is an object, `std::vector<my_obj*>*` is a pointer to an object.

Objects (rather than pointers or references) have specific lifetimes. If you create a pointer to an object with `new`, the lifetime of the object pointed to will be until you explicitly call `delete`. If you create an object as a member of another object, then that inner object's lifetime will (more or less) mirror the outer object's lifetime. If you create an object on the stack (a parameter or variable at function scope), then its lifetime is the current scope of that variable name.

Answer (score 8):

Because `bar` contains a `std::vector`, not a `std::vector *`.

It's really no different to something like this:

```
class bar
{
    int foo;  // No need to create a "new int"
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Because foo is an object, not a pointer.

```
std::vector<my_obj*>    // This is an object
std::vector<my_obj*> *  // This is a pointer to an object
                    ^^^ // Notice the extra star.
```

`new` returns a pointer:

```
new std::vector<my_obj*>();  // returns std::vector<my_obj*> *
```

PS. Your vector should probably contain objects, not pointers.

```
std::vector<my_obj>   foo;
...
foo.push_back(my_obj());
```

Otherwise you will need to manually delete all the objects in the vector when it goes out of scope (when the containing object is destroyed). I.e., if you want to keep pointers in your vector you should do one of the following:

```
// 1. Manually delete all the elements in the vector when the object is destroyed.
~bar::bar()
{
    for(std::vector<my_obj*>::iterator loop = foo.begin(); loop != foo.end(); ++loop)
    {
        delete (*loop);
    }
}

// 2. Use a smart pointer:
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<my_obj> >  foo;

// 3. Use a smart container for pointers
boost::ptr_vector<my_obj>   foo
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `std::vector` does that for you :) You don't have a pointer to `std::vector`, you're simply setting up an object of type `std::vector`, which internally allocates memory for you.

Answer (score 1):

*std::vector* in this library is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<my_obj *> foo` is different from `std::vector<my_obj *> *foo`. The second case will require you to use new while the first wll not.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `new` on `foo`, since foo is a `vector`, not a pointer to a `vector` (i.e. `std::vector<my_obj*> *foo`).

If you are coming from Java or C#, you may want to consider using `std::vector<my_obj>` (a vector of objects) instead of a vector of pointers. It really depends on what you want to do.